# The double loop

Tags: python-3.x

I try to make same result like this

0:    Fin001

1:    Fin038

2:    Fin075

3:    Fin112

4:    Fin149

5:    Fin186

6:    Fin223

7:    Fin260

8:    Fin297

9:    Fin334

here is my code

```
x = []
for a in range(0,10):
 for i in range(1,337,37):
    if a > 10:
        adstr =str(a) + ':    ' + 'Fin' + str(format(i, '0>3'))
        if i < 337:
            adstr = 'Fin' + str(format(i, '0>3'))
        else:
            adstr = 'Fin' + str(format(i, '0>3'))
    else:
        adstr =str(a) + ':    ' + 'Fin' + str(format(i, '0>3'))    
    x.append(adstr)
```

where is wrong 
i don't understand

Comment: Your problem might be difficult for you or you might be it is not yet solved but this is not how StackOverflow works. in your question, you mentioned the o/p you want and the code, one more this is expected with this i.e, your approaches and what all efforts you took to solve your problem. So we would help you further with that approach or some other approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm sure there can be a better and detailed answer to this, which I can edit later if no one else gives an answer, but from the first look I see a problem:
You start your code by `if a > 10` but that will never be true because your range goes from 0 to 10.

Plus add some `print('')` around the statements that you'd like to print and try to correct the strings that you are trying to print, since they don't seem correct either.

Hope this gives you a start.

**edit: Also if you'd like to see what you're print right now, type `print(x)` at the end of your code.**